# Weird If Else Behavior on VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

Hi good day guys I would just like to ask for your help regarding my vb.net project my if else statement is acting so weird instead of executing the code correctly when I typed in the correct answer on the text box it will show the `correctmsg` form from the if statement correctly but it will also show the wrong message form which is in the else statement. 
Please help me, thanks in advance. Here is my code :

```
Private Sub submit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles submit.Click

    If Label1.Text = "Who invented the airplane?" And TextBox1.Text = "third" Then
        Label2.Text = (Label2.Text) + 1

        correctmsg.Show()
        Label1.Text = "Who invented the telephone?"

    Else
        wrongmsg.Show()

    End If

    If Label1.Text = "Who invented the telephone?" And TextBox1.Text = "Alexander Grahambell" Then
        Label2.Text = Label2.Text + 1

        MsgBox("Your Answer is Correct!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        Label1.Text = "Who is the first president of the United States of America?"
    Else
        wrongmsg.Show()

    End If



    If Label1.Text = "Who is the first president of the United States of America?" And TextBox1.Text = "George Washington" Then

        Label2.Text = Label2.Text + 1

    Else
        wrongmsg.Show()
    End If




End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have more than one submit click handler function? or is there more code in this method than you've shown?

Comment: Also, you are aware that you can rename controls, aren't you? Wouldn't it be better to have `question` and `answer` controls than `Label1` and `TextBox1`?

Comment: @Damien I only have one submit click handler function....Yes there is more code the codes shown above is just the starting code of my program and I want to have this work so that the other parts of the code will work too :) Thanks

Comment: I think its being called more than once - in the first call the first condition is true and the label1.text is changed. Then in the second call the first if condition is false because of the label1 change

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes I am aware in renaming controls...this weird execution of my program just bothers me :(

Comment: @Geezer68 Hi sir, here is the complete view of my program wait i will just post it again thanks

Comment: Then my guess is that lower down, you have a practically identical piece of code except that it's checking whether `Label1`'s `Text` is `"Who invented the telephone?"` and for a different answer. After you're `If` branch has finished, that's what `Label1`s `Text` is, and so it's that *lower* blocks `Else` clause that's happening.

Comment: good call:) I think using a Select Case for the questions might be the way forward

Comment: @Geezer68 ah okay so select case might be the solution for this and no other tricks that I can use so that the program will not show the wrongmsg form even I typed in the correct answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've misidentified *which* `Else` block is running:

```
If Label1.Text = "Who invented the airplane?" And TextBox1.Text = "third" Then

   'This block is running

    Label2.Text = (Label2.Text) + 1

    correctmsg.Show()
    Label1.Text = "Who invented the telephone?"

Else
    'This block isn't running

    wrongmsg.Show()

End If

If Label1.Text = "Who invented the telephone?" And TextBox1.Text = "Alexander Grahambell" Then
    'This block isn't running
    Label2.Text = Label2.Text + 1

    MsgBox("Your Answer is Correct!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    Label1.Text = "Who is the first president of the United States of America?"
Else
    'THIS Block is running

    wrongmsg.Show()

End If
```

I'd move the code to change the question down to the end, or have a `Return` statement after you've changed the question, to stop the next set of blocks also checking the same answer, e.g.:

```
If Label1.Text = "Who invented the airplane?" And TextBox1.Text = "third" Then

    Label2.Text = (Label2.Text) + 1

    correctmsg.Show()
    Label1.Text = "Who invented the telephone?"
    Return 'Don't do any more checks this time around

ElseIf Label1.Text = "Who invented the airplane?"
    'Reason ElseIf (In case the question was 'who invented the telephone' then the first errormessage should not not be shown)
    wrongmsg.Show()
    Return

End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! The Return technique did the trick..Thank you very much from the bottom of my heart :) how can I give you a +1 for this? im just new here in stackoverflow :)

Comment: @user3231002 - There are upvote and downvote buttons at the top left of each answer - I can't remember whether you're allowed to use them when you're a brand new member. There's also an option (after some delay, I believe) to mark the answer that you like the best as the accepted answer, by pressing the tick mark next to the question. Also, note a few of the edits by svranken and myself to the bottom block of code that make it a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
If Label1.Text = "Who invented the airplane?" And TextBox1.Text = "third" Then
    Label2.Text = (Label2.Text) + 1

    correctmsg.Show()
    Label1.Text = "Who invented the telephone?"

ElseIf Label1.Text Is Not "Who invented the airplane?" TextBox1.Text = "third" Then
    wrongmsg.Show()
End If
```

Comment: Sir it gives me an Error 1 'Is' operator does not accept operands of type 'Long'. Operands must be reference or nullable types.

Comment: you should split every question to new form, i think

Answer (score 0):

In your code if the first `if` block is `true` it will change the Label `Label1.Text` to  `"Who invented the telephone?"`

In the same function, you have created another `if` block which is checking whether `Label1.Text = "Who invented the telephone?"` which will be `true` But you haven't changed the value in the text box so the `if` condition will fail and the `else` block will be executed.

Again in the next `if` block the conditions will fail and its `else` block will get executed.

So when you click the button once, the `wrongmsg.Show()` will be executed twice at least.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it a bit diffrently than the other answers. By using a Else If instead of having all questions in seperate If, you eleminate the chance of having the Else of other questions being called. For fun, put a break point in your code and step through each line, you'll see exactly what is hapenning.

```
If Label1.Text = "Who invented the airplane?" Then
    If TextBox1.Text = "third" Then
        Label2.Text = (Label2.Text) + 1

        correctmsg.Show()
        Label1.Text = "Who invented the telephone?"

   Else
        wrongmsg.Show()
    End If
Else If Label1.Text = "Who invented the telephone?" Then
    If TextBox1.Text = "Alexander Grahambell" Then
        Label2.Text = (Label2.Text) + 1

        correctmsg.Show()
        Label1.Text = "Who is the first president of the United States of America?"

   Else
        wrongmsg.Show()
    End If
Else If Label1.Text = "Who is the first president of the United States of America?" Then
    If TextBox1.Text = "George Washington" Then
        Label2.Text = (Label2.Text) + 1

        correctmsg.Show()

   Else
        wrongmsg.Show()
    End If
End If
```

I would also remove the duplicate code a bit.

```
Dim isCorrect As Boolean = False

If Label1.Text = "Who invented the airplane?" Then
    If TextBox1.Text = "third" Then
        isCorrect = True
        Label1.Text = "Who invented the telephone?"
    End If
Else If Label1.Text = "Who invented the telephone?" Then
    If TextBox1.Text = "Alexander Grahambell" Then
        isCorrect = True
        Label1.Text = "Who is the first president of the United States of America?"
    End If
Else If Label1.Text = "Who is the first president of the United States of America?" Then
    If TextBox1.Text = "George Washington" Then
        isCorrect = True
    End If
End If

If isCorrect Then
    Label2.Text = (Label2.Text) + 1

    correctmsg.Show()
Else
    wrongmsg.Show()
End If
```